# The style for a aside element

Tags: css, html

I have the following html5 code. I expected the style for the text **Business Ads** to be italic and color in yellow. But it comes in red.

Can only certain styles be applied to the aside element?

CSS:

```
aside h4 {
     font-style: italic !important;
     color: yellow;
 }
article h4 {
     font-style: normal;
     color: red;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <article>
        <aside>
            <h4>Business Ads</h4>
        </aside>
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a specificity issue: the first rule *is* applied, but so is the second (which overwrites any non-important styles from the first rule).

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to your issue? Please accept the answer you fond most helpfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of the way CSS specificity works. The page here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

provides a good explanation. In this case, since both style declarations refer to an h1 within a larger element, they have equal specificity, and the latest declared style takes precedence. You can override this with !important, but it's usually considered bad style because it breaks the "cascading" nature of CSS. Instead, use a more specific selector:

```
article aside h1 {

   //style goes here

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You override the rules the way you have set your CSS. Both rules target same element, so the second one will override the first one and apply to the element.

For example if you set the oppossite order to your rules like this :

```
article h4 {
    font-style: normal;
    color: red;
}

aside h4 {
    font-style: italic !important;
    color: yellow;
}
```

the second one will aply and `h4` will be yellow an italic

So if you have an `h4` also inside `article` you can use this:

```
 article aside h4 {
     font-style: italic !important;
     color: yellow;
 }
 article h4 {
     font-style: normal;
     color: red;
 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gzxqs6vo/)

Answer (score 2):

You must be more specific with the selector so that the rule it is assigned to overrides the "default" one. You can the remove the `!important` which isn't the best way to override existing rules when you can use other techniques.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/z5vfcmqd/3/)**

```
article aside h4 {
    font-style: italic;
    color: yellow;
}
article h4 {
    font-style: normal;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're targeting the same h4 element but you gave it with different styles
and the last one was read. Just delete

```
article h4 {
     font-style: normal;
     color: red;
 }
```

and remove the `!important` in the first selector.
And if you're targeting different h4 tags inside an article or aside tag, what you can do is put classes or span on them.